# Parse records by version number in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of records that have a 'Version' property. The version is stored as text. I know how to match on specific versions (e.g. `WHERE version = '1.2.3'`), but I want to be able to use comparison operators (<, >, =, etc.) on the version number (e.g. `WHERE version > '1.2.3'`).

Does anyone know of a good way to achieve this?

Comment: You are able to do so. Type `select '1.2.3' > '1.2.4'` and `select '1.2.3' > '1.2.2'` for example. Postgres compares it char-by-char.

Comment: @ConsiderMe However, if you try `select '1.2.3' > '1.2.11'` you might not be happy with the result.

Comment: @BruceAlderman I was embarrassed by ConsiderMe's advice until I realized this myself.

Comment: @BruceAlderman you are right. I assumed subsequent version notation from 1-9, since the question involved that format rather than 1.23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For *versionsort*, casting to cidr *might* be a solution. It works for the trivial cases. Non-numeric characters will probably spoil the party.

```
-- some data
DROP table meuk;
CREATE table meuk
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , version text
        );
INSERT INTO meuk(version) VALUES
        ( '1.1.1'), ( '1.1.2'), ( '1.1.11'), ( '1.1.102')
        , ( '0.1.1'), ( '2.1.2'), ( '22.1.11'), ( '0.1.102')
        ;

SELECT * FROM meuk
ORDER BY version::cidr -- cast to cidr (less restrictive than inet)
        ;
```

---

Rseult:

```
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 8
 id | version 
----+---------
  5 | 0.1.1
  8 | 0.1.102
  1 | 1.1.1
  2 | 1.1.2
  3 | 1.1.11
  4 | 1.1.102
  6 | 2.1.2
  7 | 22.1.11
(8 rows)
```